# Can't compile C++ with openmp pragmas in Eclipse Neon

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, openmp

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ project in Eclipse Neon 2 with OpenMP pragmas.

I have installed the **libgomp1** package and find / -name *gomp* provides the following output:

```
/usr/share/doc/gcc-5-base/gomp /usr/share/doc/libgomp1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.spec
```

g++ is launched with the following options:

```
 -std=c++0x -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp
```

The following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0;i++;i<r){
(...)
```

Generates this error message on the for loop line:

```
invalid controlling predicate
invalid increment expression
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have your loop test expression "i<r" and increment expression "i++" back to front/swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the order within the for-statement wrong:

1. Init
2. Stop Condition
3. Increment

So, your loop should look like this

```
for( int i=0; i<r; i++ )
```

This is what the error message is telling you:

"invalid controlling predicate" = Stop condition is invalid, because in your code, it is an increment operation

"invalid increment expression" = Increment is invalid, because in your code, it is a condition.

Comment: It should be noted that the errors are OpenMP-specific as OpenMP `for` only accepts loops of the special _canonical form_. The statement as shown in the question is otherwise meaningless but valid C++.

Comment: Thanks, yep, this important to notice.

Comment: Although the error message only happens due to OpenMP restrictions (as Hristo points out), it certainly looks like a real bug in the serial code, since the loop will never execute. So the error message is OpenMP specific, but the error in the code is not (and OpenMP helped you find a real bug!)

Comment: Well, I find kind of incompetent now :-). Thank you!